# "The operation couldn't be completed"/"Operation canceled" error message when saving to a Samba share via Files app

Tags: network, unix, sharing, smb

I'm using the Files app on my iPhone and iPad to save photos to an SMB network share provided by Samba on an Ubuntu 20.04 server.

Since around iOS/iPadOS 14.5, trying to save a new file to the share results in an error message saying:

```
The operation couldn't be completed
Operation canceled
```

Since nothing has changed server-side, this looks like a bug in iOS/iPadOS. How can the described problem be solved?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There does not seem to be any documentation from Apple on changes related to SMB in iOS/iPadOS 14.5. However, the following configuration change on the Samba server restores Files app functionality:

- Install the Samba package containing VFS modules (on Ubuntu via `apt install --no-install-recommends samba-vfs-modules`)
- Add the following line to your Samba configuration (on Ubuntu in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`) in the `[global]` section or in the relevant share section:
  `vfs objects = fruit streams_xattr`
- Restart Samba (on Ubuntu via `systemctl restart smbd.service`)

You might need to reconnect the share in the Files app. Afterwards, saving new files to the share should work again.

Documentation for the `fruit` SAMBA VFS module can be found at https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/vfs_fruit.8.html.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked perfectly fine.

Comment: This worked for me. But this is exactly why Linux will never be viable for normal consumers even Ubuntu. Every time I setup a new system I'm supposed to remember to do this in order for it to support file sharing with the most common mobile device on the planet?

Comment: @SeanO'Neil: I wouldn't remember myself, so I'm putting all the configuration I need into Ansible playbooks. Using them I can setup a new system within minutes without any manual tasks. Although not for everyone, that's the beauty of Linux ;)

Comment: When building Samba on BSD-systems, be sure to enable the `FRUIT` option - then follow the rest of @MarianRainer-Harbach's instructions.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Thank you so much @marian